Why does this integral not work?
Problem Statement:
The function $( f(x) = 2.5 - x $) and the function $ g(x) = \frac{1}{x} $ enclose a region in the first quadrant. Find the volume of the rotational body that is made by rotating this region with respect to the  $x$-axis.

Method One:
Volume generated by $ f(x) $:
$ V_f = \pi \int_{0.5}^{2} (2.5 - x)^2 \, dx $
Volume generated by $g(x) $:
$ V_g = \pi \int_{0.5}^{2} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 \, dx $
Volume of the wanted region:
$ V = V_f - V_g = \pi \left( \int_{0.5}^{2} (2.5 - x)^2 \, dx - \int_{0.5}^{2} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 \, dx \right) = 1.125 \pi $
This method works and gives the right solution according to the book.
Method Two:
This method, which I initially thought could work, does not give the correct result. Here's the thought process:
$( f(x) - g(x) $) gives us the difference between the two functions.
If we treat $( f(x) - g(x) $) as the radius for each individual disk, then the area of one general disk should be $\pi (f(x) - g(x))^2 $.
Taking the integral from $0.5$ to $2$ of $ \pi (f(x) - g(x))^2 $ should give us the volume:
$[ \pi \int_{0.5}^{2} \left((2.5 - x) - \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 \, dx $]
Geometrically, this idea seems to make sense, but the algebra and resulting volume do not match the first method's result.
Question:
Why doesn't this method work, even though it seems to make sense geometrically? Could someone explain the discrepancy?

Let's simplify the idea:  Take the lines $y = 1$ and $y=3$ and the interval $[0, 1].$ Rotate this region around the x-axis. Use your method, then compare with the geometry. What goes wrong? This gives you an idea.

This would give the same rotational volume if you added the same positive constant to both functions. Rotational value of the difference is $$\pi\int (f^2(x)-g^2(x)),dx,$$ assuming $f(x)>g(x)>0$ on the region of the intergral.

Hi @SeanRoberson. The answer I get would be different than the real answer... but I dont really understand why.

Hi @ThomasAndrews. I understand that the method you just mentioned works. However, I just dont really understand why my method also does not work. Intuitively it works, it is just finding the difference between the two functions and then integrating from a to b... could you explain in a simpler way maybe so that I would understand better? I mean that you are expressing the difference as the radius as one circle-sector

SMK, what you are integrating (from $0.5$ to $2$) is the area of a disk with radius $f(x)-g(x)$, whereas what you should is the area of an annulus: a disk with radius $f(x)$ minus a smaller disk inside with radius $g(x)$.

Hi @AnneBauval. I was wondering whether you could elaborate more on that idea, I dont really understand it but it sounds interesting. Could you answer my question maybe in depth? Thank you!

"Intuitively it works, it is just finding the difference between the two functions and then integrating from a to b ... ." What intuition did you use here? If it is just integrating the difference between two functions, why is there a square power in the integral?

Hi @DavidK. Sorry for the weird meaning. What I meant is that, if you were to graph the functions, then you would see that the radius of each disk (or maybe annulus but I dont really understand what that is) would be f(x)-g(x). Then, squaring that value and multipling by pi gives the area of that disk. Because we are multipling with a dx, then it turns into a very thin cylinder with a volume unit. Then when I say integrating from a to b, I mean adding up all these disk volumes from some x = a to some x = b.

SMK, I suggest you rather elaborate more on your wrong method (directly in your post, better than in comment). And/or "see" the slices of this solid, perpendicular to the x-axis. They are annuli, not disks.

You answered to Thomas "I understand that the method you just mentioned works". If you do, how can you not understand that yours does not, where the only difference between the two is precisely your mistake of taking $(f-g)^2$ instead of $f^2-g^2$? If that helps, apply your method separately to the volume (for $0.5\le x\le 2$) corresponding to $f(x)=2.5-x$ and $g(x)=0$, and to the volume corresponding to $f(x)=1/x$ and $g(x)=0$, and take the difference (one solid minus the other one).

The only good intuitive reason why the "disk method" makes any sense at all is that when you take the region between an axis and a curve and rotate that region around the axis, you get a solid that you can then slice perpendicular to the axis (like slicing salami) and the shape of each slice resembles a disk. In your method 2, you're implicitly saying that if you slice through the solid at $x=1$ (for example) you will get a disk of radius $f(1)-g(1)=\frac12$. But there is no way you can slice a disk of radius $\frac12$ from this solid.

In order to intuitively see how to solve this problem, you need to be able to visualize what the solid looks like when the region is rotated. In your question, the solid will look like a conical frustum on the outside, with radius $2$ at one end and $\frac12$ at the other, with a hole excavated through the middle. The hole is not less than $\frac12$ in radius anywhere. So when you slice the solid "like a salami" you get mostly very large slices (up to radius $2$, much larger than the maximum of $f(x)-g(x)$ in this region) with large holes in the middle.

Because of the hole in the middle, no slice is a disk, and the slice at coordinate $x$ has radius $f(x)$, not $f(x)-g(x)$. So in fact, geometrically it makes no sense at all to interpret $f(x) - g(x)$ as if it were the radius of a disk.

You seem to mixing something up, and your comments haven't made it clear. Here's how to view it.
Suppose $f(x) \geq g(x)$ on some interval $[a, b].$ We want to find the volume of the solid formed when this region is rotated around the $x$-axis. As $f$ dominates $g$ on this interval, its corresponding "radius" is larger, and the volume formed by rotating the area under $f$ around the $x$-axis is $$V_f = \pi \int_a ^b f(x)^2 \ dx.$$ Likewise, the volume formed for $g$ is $$V_g = \pi \int_a ^b g(x)^2 \ dx.$$ But we want the volume formed by the region between! So we need to subtract, and the desired volume is $$V_f - V_g = \pi \int_a ^b f(x)^2 - g(x)^2 \ dx.$$ To answer your main question: the radius of the disk is NOT $f(x)-g(x)$ in this case, because that would be the radius if we rotated around $g(x)$! Keep this in mind when your axis of rotation is different. Note in the figure below, although $g(x)$ is a constant function, this may be different in other cases! Here's how I tell my students: "outside squared minus inside squared," where we measure the distance from the function to the axis of rotation. Watch this video here that I created for my university's math department while a graduate student for many more examples - and note my explanations and sketches!
But the main question is why? We need to view these as annunlar regions. Take two concentric circles of radius $r$ and $R$ where $r < R.$ What's the area of the "donut" region? Intuitively, because the smaller circle contains area in the big circle, it gets double counted, so we subtract, giving the difference $\pi R^2 - \pi r^2 = \pi(R^2 - r^2).$ We see this in action in the following figures from OpenStax Calculus, Volume 2.

But I think there's also something bigger at play here: you also seem to be confusing $(x-y)^2$ and $x^2 - y^2$. We note:
$$\color{red}{\boxed{{(x-y)^2 \neq x^2 - y^2}}}$$
which is a huge misconception!

Hi Sean. I wanted to thank you for taking the time to answer my question. However, maybe my first explanation was not good enough to express what is on my mind. I will edit my first question with better explanations, so that hopefully everybody could understand little better about the problem I am stating.

It also seems that you have subtracted the smaller valued function with the bigger function. Maybe just a typo?

See the edits. The punchline is: "Be careful where you measure!"

Hi Sean. I am really sorry that I cannot really understand, but what do you mean by that the answer would have been right if I rotated with respect to g(x). Am I not rotating with respect to g(x), and how do you know that it would be right if I were to be rotating with respect to g(x)? I mean, the difference is in between f(x) and g(x)...

The instructions in the question state "...rotating this region with respect to the x-axis." You're going around the line $x = 0$, so all distances MUST be measured from there.

So should I just stick to the first method and just forget about the last method? I mean, I have quite strong intuition on the first method and it seems to be right. Is my first method right though, generally speaking? You also have quite nice videos, thank you for suggesting them

The first method is exactly how it's done. The second method doesn't account for all the volume. Read any reference on this and you'll find similar constructions. For the meantime, you should accept the answer by clicking the check if it serves its purpose.
